# .Net webservice giving a 404 error when accessed by an android app while both individually work

Tags: c#, android, .net, web-services, android-volley

I am not even sure if I should show any code, I have a web service which I created using .Net, I can access it both through browser & through Postman just fine.
I have an android app with which I use the Volley library so I can make calls, calls to Postman Echo work just fine.
I am using Jexus Manager to allow localhost to access the ISS Express server that I use to run/debug the .Net "server". Of course, I have tested whether Jexus Manager is off or on the .Net web service is accessible by Postman & browser.
It might be my Jexus configuration I guess but I did everything according to the documentation to the best of my knowledge.

I have also tried enabling Cors, but that did not make any difference.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong? It's probably something really dumb because I've been trying a LOT of things I managed to find online on and off while I was developing other parts.

**EDIT:**
Error: E/Volley: [1301] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for http://10.0.2.2:61969/ws/test
The only more detailed version of this error I could find (either searching through the methods I could run on the VolleyError or online) was the standard/default ISS 404 page which really doesn't provide any information

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to `<application`> tag inside AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Can you provide permission list mentioned in manifest file ? And what you get in error for status code 404 ?

Comment: I have updated the original post with the permissions in the manifest file & the error